# How to compare two different arrays without methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I am trying to get the freecodecamp task done. There is the task:
Compare two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays, but not both. In other words, return the symmetric difference of the two arrays.

I know how to fix it with `Array.prototype.slice()`, `Array.prototype.filter()`, `Array.prototype.indexOf()`,  `Array.prototype.concat()` and others methods. But I want to do it without methods at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @horizontt: show us some effort, post your sample code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here's how I would implement it:

```js
window.onload=function(){
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var array2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
var result = []
var resultCount=0;
for (var i1 = 0; i1 < array1.length; i1++) {
    var comparedElement = array1[i1];
    var isUnique = true;
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < array2.length; i2++) {
        if (comparedElement == array2[i2]) {
            isUnique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isUnique) {
        result[resultCount]=comparedElement;resultCount++;
    }
}


for (var i2 = 0; i2 < array2.length; i2++) {
    var comparedElement = array2[i2];
    var isUnique = true;
    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < array1.length; i1++) {
        if (comparedElement == array1[i1]) {
            isUnique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isUnique) {
        result[resultCount]=comparedElement;resultCount++;
    }
}
    
console.log(result)
}
```

The code tries to find each of the elements in an array in the other array, and if it doesn't find it, it adds it to the results array and if not, it just skips it. This might not be the most efficient way to solve this though.

Comment: I din't think he cared about that, only the comparison methods. I removed it though.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Trying to make it shorter and more optimal.

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you maybe mark this as the answer if it works out for you? That'd help me out a bit as well.